# How to reference "ext" property provided by a Groovy script plugin in my Kotlin Gradle script?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to migrate a `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts` and am stuck with this error:

```
  Line 036: ext.pluginInfo.licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
                ^ Unresolved reference: pluginInfo
```

The original `build.gradle` "includes" another script and then references `pluginInfo` from that script:

```
apply from: "rubyUtils.gradle"
pluginInfo.licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
```

This is the (shortened) part from `rubyUtils.gradle` that provides `pluginInfo` (I guess):

```
ext {
    pluginInfo = new PluginInfo()
}
```

Here is what I have come up with in Kotlin. This causes the error mentioned at the beginning:

```
apply(from = "rubyUtils.gradle")
ext.pluginInfo.licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible at all to "import" a Groovy Gradle script in a Kotlin script (apply a Groovy script plugin in a Kotlin script)?
2. If it is possible: How do I correctly refer to `pluginInfo`?
3. And what is that whole "ext" thing anyway? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you can import Groovy scripts in Kotlin and vice-versa. Unfortunately, you might encounter class loading issues.
2. `val pluginInfo by extra` is the notation you are looking for according to [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#extra_properties)
3. In short, they are an extension system that has been in Gradle for a long time and is to be used with care. Again, have a look at the documentation linked above for more details.